# MySQL - is there any way to check if a view is referenced by other views?

Tags: mysql

I have a development MySQL db which i am cleaning up.  I am deleting some test views.

How can I check if a view is referenced by other views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an information schema table which stores view definitions. You could use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.VIEWS 
WHERE table_schema = 'your schema' 
AND view_definition LIKE '%referenced_view%';
```

Which will give you back all views that reference 'referened_view' in their definition

Comment: U ROK!  perfect, spot on.  UPVOTED + ACCEPTED!  tks :)